# How to standardize URLs?

Tags: url, browser, url-shortener

I am building a small URL Shortener service, and one of the requirements is that this tool must be able to recognize aready-shortened URL to give the hash again, instead of generating new hash.

In order to do this effectively, I have to break any given URL down to small parts, and store them in a way that is unified across the system.

For instance:

```
http://subdomain.domain.com:8081/example.php?query=true#hash
```

Can be translated  into small parts:

```
{
    protocol: "http:",
    hostname: "domain.com",
    subdomain: "subdomain",
    port: "8081",
    pathname: "/example.php",
    query: "query=true",
    hash: "#hash"
}
```

With those parts, once again, I put them together to make an URL.

Now imagine this scenario when comparing (reference #1):

```
http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved/
```

And (reference #2):

```
http:////www.iana.org//domains//reserved
```

Or even (reference #3):

```
http://www.iana.org//domains\\/reserved
```

The strings are completely different, but they both return the same page(I believe the browsers correct it) when punched in. In order to detect them as the same URL, I added another simple string-replace layer in order to standardize (or whichever the correct verb is) them:

1. Using `protocol + "//" + subdomain + hostname + ":" + portname` to standardize the first part of the URL.
2. Replace all multiple slashes `/` by a single slash `/` in `pathname`.
3. Adding `query + hash` to complete the URL.

**My question**:

1. Should I perform such replacement (step 2)? I am concerned about the behaviors of non-standard browsers that might return different addresses (or error) when punched in URLs such as ones in reference #2 and reference #3.
2. What are some other ways that people can, intentionally or by mistake, enter different string for the same URL that is still resolved correctly by the browser? Overall, I need to detect those situation in order to minimize the chance of getting same URL twice.

Comment: Note that even completely distinct URLs can resolve to the same content.  Trivial examples include using IP address instead of hostname, but more generally, the host may employ URL rewriting.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Noted. I would have to keep it in mind. But I'm more concern about people playing with the URL, by adding random characters to it. I'm not sure if there would be any perfect solution, but the more optimal the better.